# C# Universal Windows StreamSocket clients not connecting to StreamSocketListener server

Tags: c#, sockets, server, uwp

I am trying to use C# and UWP to write a simple socket server. So far, I have written a SocketServer class in C# that you can subclass; I want it to be like a socket server in Node.js.

However, I have tried connecting to this server from the Python REPL and from a C# client but both of the times the connection timed out. I compared my code with the StreamSocket example from Microsoft on Github, and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I do not know if it is a problem with my code or with some network configurations on my computer.

Here is my server superclass:

```
...    
    abstract class SocketServer
    {
        public SocketServer()
        {

        }

        public async void Listen(String port)
        {
            StreamSocketListener serverSocket = new StreamSocketListener();
            await serverSocket.BindServiceNameAsync("8003");

            serverSocket.ConnectionReceived += ClientConnectionReceived;

            Debug.WriteLine("Server started");
        }

        private void ClientConnectionReceived(
            StreamSocketListener sender,
            StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Client connection received");

            OnConnection(args.Socket);

            DataReader reader = new DataReader(args.Socket.InputStream);

            try
            {
                // fill in later
            }
            catch
            {
                // fill in later
            }
        }

        abstract protected void OnConnection(StreamSocket socket);

        abstract protected void OnData(String data);

        abstract protected void OnEnd(); 
    }
}
```

Here is the subclass of that server:

```
class Subclass: SocketServer
    {
    override protected void OnConnection(StreamSocket socket)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Got connection");
    }

    override protected void OnData(String data)
    {

    }

    override protected void OnEnd()
    {

    }
}
```

Here is the code that instantiates the server (in App.xaml.cs):

```
        public App()
        {
            ...
            Debug.WriteLine("==========================");

            Subclass manager = new Subclass();
            manager.Listen("8003");
        }
```

And finally, here is the C# client code (in App.xaml.cs):

```
public App()
        {
            ...
            Debug.WriteLine("========================");

            StartClient();
        }

        async void StartClient()
        {
            try
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("About to connect");
                StreamSocket socket = new StreamSocket();
                Debug.WriteLine("Made StreamSocket");
                await socket.ConnectAsync(new HostName("localhost"), "8003");
                Debug.WriteLine("Connected");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Exit();
            }
        }
```

It prints "About to connect" and "Made SocketStream", but after a while there is a timeout error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You aren't awaiting the async call in theconstructor, you need to use .Result.

Comment: What is .Result? StreamSocket does not have a property named Result. And are you talking about the server or the client?

Comment: `public async void Listen(String port)` should be `public async Task` not void. Then in `App()` you can call `manager.Listen("8003").Wait()` (not result, my mistake). Don't use async void, always use async Task unless you are using it as an event handler.

Comment: By the way, you have to use the `Wait` call, you can't mark constructors as `async`.

Comment: I did those things, but the error still comes up. The message is: `Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
WinRT information: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you connecting from another machine ? You cannot connect to a StreamSocketListener from another app or process running in the same computer, not even with a [loopback exemption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh780593.aspx). You will need to run the client in a different machine.

Comment: Can you please comment on why we can't connect to a StreamSocketListener if there is a loopback exemption? What is the point of the loopback exemption, then? Is there any other method of connecting to a socket on UWP that would get around the security issues?

Comment: I ran into the exact same problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56610586/uwp-unable-to-create-localhost-connection-between-two-apps). In the end I want to run both apps on different PCs, but for testing it would be very helpful to run both apps on 1 PC. Is there any way around this?